# Better ways to create an interactive list?

Tags: listview, longlist

I have a custom list created on SharePoint which is being used by users to create requests.

The list has multiple one line Text columns and Check Boxes.

Users raise around 15-20 such request every day. I want to make it easier for them to raise these requests, as good amount of time is being sent in raising it.

Could someone please advise an easier and more interactive way to do it on SharePoint.
[image: Sample List]

Comment: Is it like this to then end of the form? How people know what they need to request, by field label or codes next to the checkboxes?

Comment: By field label.

Comment: The form has around 30 such field labels. Users request one or many of them.

Comment: Those codes seem barely human-readable, are they necessary in the interaction?

Comment: Not necessary. Its "Good to have" information for the users. The field labels consists of the batch jobs with those codes.

Comment: "Not necessary" - from your own words. Return to the drawing board, involve your managers and trim the fat.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some of the following (I do not know how easy it is to implement them in share point) :

- Use meaningfull defaults. Based on your use cases provide defaults that most likely are the correct values. For example if users are usually working for long periods on one project, automatically populate PROJECT field based on previous entry of the user.
- Change the long list of checkboxes to a searchable tag list like the one used by the stack exchange or something similar that provide the same functionality:
  [image]
- Replace the long codes with mouse over tooltips to reduce the information overload and the size of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions which can help you.

1. I can see there are some required and optional fields but they are not grouped together. The required fields can be grouped so that immediate requests are faster to attain.
2. The checkboxes can also be grouped together to have a certain group of items being checked at once, it's easier to categorise them if you know the groups based on data about how the users fill up the information